# How to bound sum of 3 variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, bounds

I want summation of 3 variables to always equal to a number, in this case 1, but I don't know how to make it happen. For example in the following problem I am trying to find maximum value of "resourceOut/maximumTime" which is a function of x1, x2, x3 but while finding the maximum I want x1, x2, x3 to be equal to 1. (xi is the inital guess value for x1, x2 and R can be any positive number.

```
function Resource(xi,R)

    x = fminsearch(@relations, xi);

    x(1)
    x(2)


    function goldenRatio = relations(xi)

        x1 = xi(1);
        x3 = xi(2);

        x2 = 1 - x1 - x3;
        x3 = 1 - x1 - x2;
        x1 = 1 - x2 - x3;

        R1 = R * x1 * 0.1;
        R2 = R * x2 * 0.25;
        R3 = R * x3 * 0.50;

        T1 = ((((R1)^2)*100)^0.45+1800);
        T2 = ((((R2)^2)*100)^0.45+1800);
        T3 = ((((R3)^2)*100)^0.45+1800);
        elapsedTimes =[T1 T2 T3];

        resourceOut = R1 + R2 + R3;
        maximumTime = max(elapsedTimes);
        goldenRatio = -resourceOut/maximumTime;

    end



end
```

Comment: It is not clear what you’re asking.

Comment: So you're given `x1` and `x3` and you want to calculate the value of `x2` such that `x1 + x2 + x3 = 1`? Is `x1 + x3` always guaranteed to be less than 1? That seems an awful lot of code. Are you sure all of it is necessary to reproduce your problem? Please post only a [mre].

Comment: So  I am trying to divide my resource for 3 jobs each have another formulation and according to that I will calculate best divison for optimum out/maximumtime.